# Check if size has been set with JavaScript in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, coding-style, size

I was wondering if there was a way in JavaScript to check if the size of an element has previously been set? Even though this obviously wont work, this is kind of what I need to happen.

```
if(element.style.width === undefined)
    element.style.width = 'auto';
```

I was wondering if this might work due to a non set opacity returning full. Maybe the same applies to...

```
element.style.width = element.style.width; // If not set then it will set it to default value?
```

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

Using this code I have managed to get it working in IE8. IE7 and 6 still are not working though, any suggestions?

```
element[e].style.width = element[e].style.width;
element[e].style.height = element[e].style.height;
if(element[e].currentStyle)
{
    element[e].style.width = element[e].currentStyle.width;
    element[e].style.height = element[e].currentStyle.height;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to check that the element's inline style has been set or that a CSS rule has already set a style?

Comment: Well any sort of width really, if the width has not already been set, then set it. I need to do this to get opacity working in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my post sort of dropped of the radar, I eventually fixed it by applying this property.

```
zoom: 1;
```

It then worked in IE6, IE7 and IE8.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, you can check an element's width using

```
var width = element.currentStyle.width;
```

The default value (i.e. if the width has not been set by any style rule or script) is `auto`.